# How to make a Input be taken as a variable in VBScript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to be able to take an input and use it within my VBScript.

```
@echo off
set var=Input
echo "%var%"
pause
```

Comment: Can you describe your desired overall solution? Right now I have to assume that it could mean command line or function/method but that could be wrong.

Comment: What VBScript? The code snippet you posted is batch code.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm thinking you mean this...

```
%%%var%%%
```

Comment: ....Makes sense!

Comment: That makes no sense at all. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?